# XSD maxLength and minLength applied to integer

Tags: xml, xsd, integer, xsd-validation, xml-validation

I am having some trouble finding out how to tell the XSD that the data of a field has to have an minimum length of 12 digits and a maximum length of 14 digits. Is there someone who knows how to do this because `minlength` and `maxlength` can only be used for strings.

```
<xs:simpleType name="timestamp_vorige_inspectie">
    <xs:restriction base="xs:integer">
        <xs:minLength value="12"/>
    </xs:restriction>
</xs:simpleType>
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use `xs:pattern` to restrict the number of digits to be in your range:

```
  <xs:simpleType name="timestamp_vorige_inspectie">
    <xs:restriction base="xs:integer">
      <xs:pattern value="\d{12,14}"/>
    </xs:restriction>
  </xs:simpleType>
```

`\d` is a regular expression construct that matches any digit.  `{12,14}` specifies the allowed number of the preceding matches.

Comment: maybe you can help me with this also  the field above is about a date time but without any slashes or other symbols is it still possible to check if it is a date?

Comment: You can use regular expressions or assertions to get part way there, but really you should use `xs:date` directly because the interoperability benefits of ISO 8601 compliance will far outweigh those of following any other idiosyncratic date formatting preferences you might have.

Answer (score 4):

Looking at https://www.w3.org/TR/xmlschema-2/#integer you can specify the `totalDigits` as 14 to have something similar to maxLength as 14. You can also specify `minInclusive` as `100000000000`.